# What is the URL for Google reCAPTCHA Admin Console?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

The link to the admin console isn't working - it shows a 404 page. I need to access this to generate a site-key.
Link: https://google.com/recaptcha/admin
OR: https://google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

I want to use reCAPTCHA v3 so I need to use this link to make it. How do I access the reCAPTCHA admin console?

Anyone comment if they are having similar issues please.

Answer (score 24):

I too struggled to find links to Google's reCAPTCHA Admin Console; surprisingly it is not linked from any of the [reCAPTCHA docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha)!?

Anyway, try this:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/

Comment: thank you!!  Its 2022 and its crazy that we need a stackoverflow question & answer for this.

Comment: Note I've since moved to [hCaptcha](https://www.hcaptcha.com/) which can be used as a drop-in replacement for reCaptcha.

Comment: that's interesting. I didn't know the alternative. I'll check them out.